# R how can I present table as horizontal rather than vertical

Tags: r

I'm new to R.
How can I present a table using R to be horizontal rather than vertical?

I have 
[Have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9p9Q.png)

but I want 
[want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0JCH.png)